# My app does not skip to the starting destination unless touch the screen

Tags: kotlin, android-actionbar, themes, android-jetpack-compose

I designed an Android app with Jetpack Compose. I did not change anything in `themes.xml`, though my app does not skip to the starting destination of my app. A screen appears and does not go away unless i touched screen. When i change the parent line in `themes.xml`, `android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar` to `android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar.FullScreen` then app works fine but I don't want to make it fullscreen. Is it possible that is a bug ?

```
<style

        name="Theme.TradeJournal" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar"> // this line 

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/purple_200</item>

    </style>
```

---

**themes.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style

        name="Theme.TradeJournal" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/purple_200</item>

    </style>

   
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifests :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sevban.tradejournal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
    <application
        android:name=".TradeJournalApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TradeJournal"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".view.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TradeJournal">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define a parent theme and create NoActionBar as it child as shown below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/calibri_regular</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppSplash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/app_logo</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">300</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar</item>
</style>
```

And in Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="****"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppSplash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Main Activity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
    splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
    setContent {
        Content()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. I suspect that it might occuring because of new android 12 splash screen stuff. But i have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Okay so Splash Screen API is creating issue. In that case you need to create separate theme for splash launch

Comment: You can try the editted answer which first takes theme for splash api then main theme for application @SevbanBayır

Comment: This also did not work but i discovered that the problem is only occuring on my physical device (XIAOMI Poco x3Pro) while i am using emulator it does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

It was a general issue that is debating in issuetracker.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227926002

Especially Xiaomi devices undergo this problem.